# VSCode Postfix Snippet Target previous word with dot notation

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to write a VSCode snippet which accomplishes the following:

- I write

```java
myVariable
```

- then I add on

```java
myVariable.toradians
```

- and press enter. The text is then replaced with:

```java
Math.toRadians(myVariable)
```

This is my attempt at this:

```json
"To Radians": {
    "prefix": ".toradians",
    "body": [
        "Math.toRadians(${TM_CURRENT_WORD})"
    ],
    "description": "Wrap in Math.toRadians()"
}
```

However, this does not have the desired affect. Instead, when I write

```java
myVariable.toradians
```

and press enter, the line becomes the following:

```java
myVariableMath.toRadians(toradians)
```

Why does `TM_CURRENT_WORD` target the prefix word, rather than the word the prefix is operating on? How can I accomplish my desired functionality?

I've read the page on snippets from VSCode's website, and looked at examples, but I can't figure out how to get this exact functionality.

I'm aware that I can change the snippet to this:

```json
"To Radians": {
    "prefix": [".toRadians", ".toradians"],
    "body": [
        "Math.toRadians(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT})"
    ],
    "description": "Wrap in Math.toRadians()"
}
```

and I can select the word, then use the notation to get the desired end string. However, I'd like to make it so that it captures the word I'm operating on.

Comment: It has not progressed any further, and there have been no solutions. It sounds like I'll need to submit a feature request to VSCode on github.

Comment: Have you submitted a request yet? If so, please share the link here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get the variable after obtaining the code fragment, but write the variable first, and then hope the code fragment is corrected for you?

```
    "To Radians": {
        "prefix": ".toradians",
        "body": [
            "Math.toRadians($1)"
        ],
        "description": "Wrap in Math.toRadians()"
    }
```

[image]

> `TM_CURRENT_WORD`: The contents of the word under cursor or the empty string

So the description in your problem is not surprising.

If you want to achieve the effect you want, you may be more useful to submit your idea in [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose).